# Find the limit cycles of $\dot r =r(1-r^2)$, $\dot \theta=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Apparently $r(t)=1$ is a limit cycle for the above system. Can anyone please explain why?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I assume that $r(t)\geq0$ for all $t$. Since
\begin{align}
\dot{r}=r\left(1-r^2\right)
\end{align}
we have for some constant $t_0\in\mathbb{R}$ :
\begin{align}
t+t_0&=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{r\left(1-r^2\right)}\\
&=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{r\left(1+r\right)\left(1-r\right)}\\
&=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{r}-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{1+r}+\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{1-r}\\
&=\ln r-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(1+r\right)-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|1-r\right|\\
&=\ln\left(\frac{r}{\sqrt{\left|1-r^2\right|}}\right).
\end{align}
So we get
\begin{align}
\frac{r}{\sqrt{\left|1-r^2\right|}}=\mathrm{e}^{t+t_0}
\end{align}
that is
\begin{align}
\frac{r^2}{\left|1-r^2\right|}=\mathrm{e}^{2\left(t+t_0\right)}.
\end{align}

- If $0\leq r\leq1$, then we have
  \begin{align}
  r^2=\mathrm{e}^{2\left(t+t_0\right)}\left(1-r^2\right)
  \end{align}
  and solving for $r^2$ and taking the square root yields the solution
  \begin{align}
  r(t)=\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\left(t+t_0\right)}}{\sqrt{{1+\mathrm{e}^{2\left(t+t_0\right)}}}}
  \end{align}
  so $\lim r(t)=1$ as $t\to+\infty$.
- If $1\leq r$, then
  \begin{align}
  r(t)=\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\left(t+t_0\right)}}{\sqrt{{\mathrm{e}^{2\left(t+t_0\right)}-1}}}
  \end{align}
  so we get once again $\lim r(t)=1$ as $t\to+\infty$.

Now, for any initial data $\left(r_0,\theta_0\right)\in\mathbb{R}_+\times[0,2\pi)$, we find that
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle r(t)=\frac{r_0\mathrm{e}^{t}}{\sqrt{1+r_0^2\left(\mathrm{e}^{2t}-1\right)}}\\
\theta(t)=t+\theta_0
\end{cases}.
\end{align}
[image] [image]

Comment: It's overkill to find the explicit solution. One can deduce the qualitative behaviour just by looking at the signs of the factors in $dr/dt=r(1-r)(1+r)$.

Comment: @HansLundmark I do not think that integrating some logarithms and doing some simple algebra is overkill. I've proposed an explicit answer; if you have a different approach, you can post another answer.

Comment: How would you solve the same question for the system $$\dot r =r(1-r^2)(e^r+r^e)\qquad \dot \theta=1\ ?$$

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your answer, I'm just mentioning that there is another way that requires less effort.

Comment: @Did For your system, I would certainly not try to find an explicit formula. But it is not the same question : the system in the OP can be integrated without any problem whereas yours looks terrible! Where did you encounter it ?

Comment: Please replace "terrible" by "playful". More seriously, omitting the qualitative arguments which allow to fully solve the OP's problem and the one in my comment is, imho, a disservice to the OP. One can dig holes in the ground with a spoon or with a shovel, even for medium sizes holes I prefer the shovel, even if I would have the time to dig my hole with a spoon.

Comment: @Did This is quite subjective : in the OP, we are asked to explain why $r=1$ is a limit cycle without any condition, so explicitely solving the system (for free, it is just standard integrations) and taking the limit $t\to+\infty$ is a good explanation for this problem. Now, I agree that we can not do it for trickier problems, and I also agree that one could solve it with some other arguments and less calculus. The way you want to solve it depends on you : I like explicit method (when I can do it), and if you want another one and post it, you're welcome :)

Comment: The power/structure/scope/applicability of an argument are very much *objective*, it seems. By the way, being myself generally inclined to explicit solutions, I feel at ease to declare that *in the present case* the existence of an explicit solution (probably not so direct to the OP than you say, however) is more a hindrance than an asset for a correct understanding of the situation.

Comment: @Did I find your analysis a bit exaggerated : the OP looked for an explanation (these are her/his words). If she/he encounters any issue why the integration part in my post, she/he can ask me for clarification. The question was : "provide an explanation for this system", and my answer is : "I can explicitely solve THIS system, and taking the limit gives the explanation". I honestly think that this is to the OP to say that this answer is to long or too complicated. Furthermore, there is no any other answer, so it seems (for now) that there is not another solution that is obvious to everyone.

Comment: "there is no any other answer, so it seems (for now) that there is not another solution that is obvious to everyone" This deduction is obviously wrong. Please do not feel an obligation to defend your posts to the absurd.

Comment: @Did I do not want to talk about this anymore. I think that this post gives a good explanation to the OP. I keep saying that if someone has another explanation, she/he is welcome to post it, especially if it is more "obvious" . All that matters is that the OP understand what happens.